# Why is Java 8 JDK recommended for GlassFish 4.1?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

On the GlassFish homepage it is stated that

> Java EE 7 requires JDK 7 or above, JDK 8 u20 or above is recommended for GlassFish 4.1.

So I am wondering, **why it is recommended to use it under the JDK 8, as GlassFish 4.1 is a Java EE 7 application server?**

Is it just because that I will be able to use the new Java 8 functionalities? Or are there deeper reasons for this like stability, know bugs etc.
So does the GlassFish really runs *better* on the JDK 8 than on the JDK 7, or may I ignore this statement and just install it under JDK 7, if I do not use the new functionalities provided under Java SE 8?

Comment: EE versions and JDK versions are released at different times, so they're not expected to always match.  The quoted statement says you need JDK 7 or above, so use any JDK version that meets that criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I am wondering, why it is recommended to use it under the JDK 8, as
>   GlassFish 4.1 is a Java EE 7 application server?

I guess they just recommend to use the newest compatible non-beta Java version which in this case is Java 8. The Java EE specs version (in this case Java EE 7) which is implemented by Glassfish 4 and the JDK version which is required (or which can be used) to run the server are two different things.

**Also note that Java 7 has its EOL (End of Life) in April, 2015**. There will be no further updates for Java 7 so at some point you'll have to switch to Java 8 anyway.

> Is it just because that I will be able to use the new Java 8
>   functionalities?

This could be one reason for you to use JDK 8.

> Or are there deeper reasons for this like stability, know bugs etc.

I guess there may be some bugs in JDK 7 which are fixed or do not occur in JDK 8, but this shouldn't be anything critical. In terms of stability I think the values are similar when not the same.

> So does the GlassFish really runs better on the JDK 8 than on the JDK
>   7, or may I ignore this statement and just install it under JDK 7, if
>   I do not use the new functionalities provided under Java SE 8?

I wouldn't say that Glassfish runs better, but I would also recommend to use the latest compatible Java version. But you can currently also safely ignore the statement and use JDK 7.

For some additional information, [this spring.io blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/21/java-8-in-enterprise-projects) contains a nice summary about Java 8 in enterprise projects and with various application servers.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that was understood for GF to recommend using Java 8 is to leverage on new functionality it offers, such as SNI support for example. However, GF itself is not yet making full use of it.